# Remove cursor and restrict the user from typing in jquery-choosen select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-chosen

I am using https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ select box the issue is when i select one option i don't want to show cursor in that box so as to restrict user typing anything in that box, please help to solve my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to disable the search box for a particular select?

Chosen has a `disable_search_threshold` option that can be used to disable the search box if there are less than *n* results.

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#hide-search-on-single-select

For example:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
```

Would disable the box if there are less than 10 options.

If you want to disable it always I guess you could just set a really high number:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 999999});
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am explaining you the whole scenario, i want to select only one option that option i can easily select but i can type also in the same textbox this i need to disable, so user cannot type after he selects option from dropdown, please help if you can.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand exactly what you want. Please post some example code, ideally with a JS fiddle.

Comment: I have added image to my post please check it.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do what you want, sorry. You'd have to dig into the guts of the Chosen code and modify it.